# TI AM335x memory address definition header files?

Tags: c, header, definition, memory-address, gpio

Are there any header files containing memory address definitions for the AM335x type
processors?

Can't find any such header files in the SDK: ti-sdk-am335x-evm-07.00.00.00

I would like to list the state and configuration for all GPIOs, but it seems incredibly
tedious to map them all up by hand. There must exist some pre-made definitions. Where
can I find them please?

Comment: What definitions do you mean? If you mean those provided as preprocessor macros when you include some header files, you can use something like `printf '#include <FOO.h>\n' | arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7 -E -dD - | sed -ne 's|^#[\t ]*define[\t ][\t ]*||p'` to list those. The GCC parameters `-E -dD` are the key, as it tells GCC to dump the preprocessor macros without compiling anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

[Sitara Starterware](http://www.ti.com/tool/starterware-sitara)

Seems to contain header files with base addresses for GPIO pins etc...